# React js rename & destructure array length

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

I have a reduce function like below:

```
let el = scopes.reduce ((tot, {actions}) => tot + actions.length, 0);
```

I tried to transform it like this, but it seems that it is not the correct way:

```
let el = scopes.reduce ((tot, {actions.length: len}) => tot + len, 0);
```

Is there a way to do this or it is not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were close, but you use nesting rather than dot notation:

```
// Outer −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−v−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−v
let el = scopes.reduce((tot, {actions: {length: len}}) => tot + len, 0);
// Inner −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

Live Example:

```js
const scopes = [
    {actions: [1, 2, 3]},
    {actions: []},
    {actions: [4, 5]}
];
let el = scopes.reduce((tot, {actions: {length: len}}) => tot + len, 0);
console.log(el); // 5
```

The key thing to remember with destructuring is that the syntax is identical to object and array literals, complete with nesting; it's just that the information flow is the other direction. In an object literal, for instance, the data flows right to left, from the source (`source`) to the target (`prop`):

```
let source = 42;
let obj = {prop: source};
//           <−−−−−*
```

in destructuring, the data flows left to right, from the source (`prop`) to the target (`target`):

```
let {prop: target};
//     *−−−−−>
console.log(target); // 42
```

and the target can be a variable, an object property, or even another destructuring pattern. That's what we're using above: The target of the `actions` property is the destructuring pattern `{length: len}`, which puts the value of `length` into the variable `len`. Here's Figure 7-1 from my new book (see my profile for links):

[image: Figure 7-1 from JavaScript: The New Toys]

---

You could also use shorthand notation and use `length` in your callback:

```
let el = scopes.reduce((tot, {actions: {length}}) => tot + length, 0);
```

Live Example:

```js
const scopes = [
    {actions: [1, 2, 3]},
    {actions: []},
    {actions: [4, 5]}
];
let el = scopes.reduce((tot, {actions: {length}}) => tot + length, 0);
console.log(el); // 5
```

Comment: initial value `0` is not required though.

Comment: @AZ_ - It is, for two reasons: 1. The values from the array are not simple values, they're objects we're extracting information from. 2. We don't know that the array isn't empty (`reduce` will throw on an empty array if there's no seed value).

Comment: ahh ok I get it, for the first element it won't get the length.